# How do you get the docroot directory?

Tags: debug

I'm trying to include a file in the docroot when I'm in the admin area. (Yes, I know this is bad form: I'm only doing it for debugging purposes.) How do I get the fully qualified docroot directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// server document directory
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

// wordpress install directory 
$dir = ABSPATH;
```

to include safely with wordpress

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'load_a_file');
function load_a_file(){
    if( is_admin() ){
        $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        include_once( $dir . '/file.php' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I just found the answer in wp-admin/admin.php. Line 30:

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/wp-load.php');
```

I was expecting some sort of wp_...() function.